# Log4j Duplicating

Tags: java, log4j

I am new to logging and I am having an issue where the Logger stacks up its output in my console (NetBeans).  This normally isn't a problem because the java program only is called one time, but out of curiosity from this point forward I am curious what I am doing wrong.

To duplicate the problem, if I run the JUnit test file for my program, I only initialize the class in:

```
 MyClassTest{ 
      MyClass instance = new MyClass();   // INITIALIZE MY CLASS WITH LOGGER          

      MyClassTest(){}
      testMethod1(){}
      testMethod2(){}
 }
```

But for each my MyClass's methods (which have logging in them) when the test executes method n, n duplicates of the logging messages appear.  This is clearly wrong.

Example:

```
Method1() {
    logger.info("Applying Resources");
}

Method2() {
    logger.info("Getting the entity of the URL response");
}
```

testMethod1 Output:

```
 INFO  root - Applying Resources (Strings), (Region)
 0 [main] INFO root  - Applying Resources
```

testMethod2 Output:

```
  INFO  root - Getting the entity of the URL response
  455 [main] INFO root  - Getting the entity of the URL response
  455 [main] INFO root  - Getting the entity of the URL response
```

This continues the more times I test the n'th method.

What am I missing here?

Code:

```
public class MyClass {
    public Logger logger;

    public MyClass() {
        logger = null; //Debug, info, warning, error, fatal
        logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    }
}
```

Comment: log4j 1 or 2? I think you need to set the 'additiviy' property to false, otherwise you get this type of duplicated logging. See here for Additvity info > http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity

Comment: log4j 1. This looks promising and has gotten rid of the topmost logging message which is a duplicate.  But the repetition still persists with the [main] logs.  Should I move to Log4j 2?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it wasn't obvious from my comment above:

```
<Logger name="com.foo.Bar" level="trace" additivity="false">
```

Or

```
public void setAdditivity(boolean additive)
```

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#setAdditivity(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that deleting this line solved my problem:

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

With regard to setting additivity to false, this was a solution to removing the initial

```
INFO  root - Applying Resources
```

Which was being written despite the stacking of the logging messages.